Why `proc_open` don't work using Windows options
System

Operating system: Windows 10
Terminal: PowerShell
Php: 8.3.2

✅ The following code works as expected
$process = proc_open(
    "php -S localhost:8000 -t www/",
    array(
        array("pipe", "r"),
        array("pipe", "w"),
        array("pipe", "w"),
    ),
    $pipes,
    __PATH_PROJECT__
);

Running new process that start php web server.
Whatever I want use "create_new_console" (the new process has a new console, instead of inheriting its parent's console) option available for windows but:
⛔ The following code does not work for an unknown reason (without any warning/error)
$process2 = proc_open(
    "php -S localhost:8000 -t www/",
    array(
        array("pipe", "r"),
        array("pipe", "w"),
        array("pipe", "w"),
    ),
    $pipes,
    __PATH_PROJECT__,
    array(
        "bypass_shell" => true,
        "create_new_console" => true
    )
);


proc_get_status:
array(9) {
  ["command"]=>
  string(29) "php -S localhost:8000 -t www/"
  ["pid"]=>
  int(10944)
  ["cached"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["running"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["signaled"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["stopped"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["exitcode"]=>
  int(1)
  ["termsig"]=>
  int(0)
  ["stopsig"]=>
  int(0)
}

Even if I try to set an empty array as an option, the new "process" never starts (why ?).
Documentation related: proc_open
Thanks in advance for your help 

Just out of curiosity, could you try running this with the Windows Command Prompt instead of PowerShell? I just want to see if the shell itself it the problem.

I have same problem on both

How are you invoking the PHP script? Just php file.php?

Yes exactly
(my message was too short*)
